# What is the linear dimension/mass/possible energy state of the smallest trackable orbital debris item?

Tags: debris

What is the threshold of detection for small orbital debris? How small can something get before it can no longer be reliably tracked (and therefore avoided)?

Given that collision energy is dependent on the delta-V of the parties to a collision, and that some extreme cases may be unlikely or absurd e.g. geosynchronous vs "retrograde geosynchronous(?)", how much collision energy could an untrackable debris item deliver to an unsuspecting space vehicle? In other words, how bad could the "hidden hazard" actually get?

Comment: The size of trackable objects is discussed in answers to [If an unknown ship entered Earth orbit, would it be detected?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/8375/4660)

Comment: I'm certain that the real answer to this question is a military secret.

Answer (score 1):

The main method for detecting small objects is radar. An object's visibility to radar is expressed as its [radar cross-section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_cross-section) (RCS). This is a measure of how much radar energy is reflected by the object to the radar antenna.
There is no direct relationship between size and RCS. A few examples: a highly reflective object (e.g. a [corner reflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_reflector)) has a large RCS even if it's small, a stealth aircraft (like the B-2) has a small RCS despite its large size.
There is one limit: a radar can't detect objects much smaller than its wavelength. The [AN/FPS-80 Cobra Dane radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Space_Surveillance_Network#Shemya_and_Diyarbakir_Radar_Sites) works in the [L band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar) with a wavelength of 15-30 cm.

Comment: So one could imagine a bolt - say 10cm long x 1 or 2 cm diameter whizzing about, and potentially striking a valued (perhaps human-occupied) orbital craft with a closing delta-V of several kms/sec, and such an object being completely untrackable and therefore unavoidable. Kind of a scary prospect.

Comment: @AnthonyX the minimum trackable size decreases as technology advances.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea-based_X-band_Radar has a higher frequency, and thus shorter wavelength.  Ka band radars are becoming more common, and those have millimeter wavelengths.  However, as Mark Adler said, it's a state secret, so you will never know how well it can be done unless you are the one doing it.